# Rust installation fails on Windows Subsystem for Linux: could not rename component file

Tags: installation, rust, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install Rust on the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) by running the following command which is provided officially [here](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/install.html):

> `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`

I've installed Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store.

The problem is that the fails with 5 similar errors:

> error: could not rename component file from '/home/thesdev/.rustup/tmp/glf5z1z643ehld0x_dir/bk' to '/home/thesdev/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/share/man'
>
> ...
>
> error: failed to install component: 'rust-docs-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu', detected conflict: '"share/doc/rust/html"'

[image: Screenshot of the installation process]

Screenshot is from VS Code. Trying it in the Ubuntu application results in the same errors.

Comment: try `strace` and see what syscall fails

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) I down voted because the same principle applies as Image of terminal output

Comment: @Stargateur I did it because it was lengthy. I included the more important parts of the output as text in the question though/

Comment: the is no problem, question can have a lot of character in it. Image can't be copied, mobile user and low connection user will prefer download 5ko than an image of 5Mo

Comment: @the8472 I'm not sure which part I should post but here is the last part of the output: [![wsl-error.png](https://i.postimg.cc/9fTKQmTG/Untitled.png)](https://postimg.cc/hJDpCq2j)

Comment: @the8472 perhaps this is more useful: [strace-log](https://pastebin.com/07w3Zi23). I guess `stat("/home/thesdev/.terminfo", 0x7fffd10d32c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)` is where the problem starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that adding sudo to the start of the command does the trick.

Comment: Yes, this simple trick did the job for me on plain Windows 8 :)

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, you need to close Visual Studio Code and run the command directly at the WSL prompt. The underlying issue is among the most-encountered WSL bugs:

- [npm package fails to install "npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied"](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/14)
- [Unable to save file when inotify is in use (using Node)](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1956)
- [EACCES when renaming folder that is being watched from nodejs](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3395)

I wouldn't be surprised if virus scanners could trigger this as well, not just Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 4):

After several failed installations with the same error, I had to nuke my `.rustup` directory. I then ran the Rust installer with sudo. I recommend also temporarily turning off your antivirus protection, as that seems to cause issues.

The entire sequence of commands:

```
$ sudo rm -rf ./home/<your_username>/.rustup
$ curl 'https://sh.rustup.rs' -sSf > rustinstall.sh
$ chmod +x rustinstall.sh
$ sudo ./rustinstall.sh -y
```

Comment: ^ is the only solution which worked for me.
I did a 
`curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs > rustinstall.sh`
and 
`sudo chmod +x ./rustinstall.sh`
in between

Comment: Indeed, the `chmod +x` is necessary!

Answer (score 1):

**Potential solution - disable your real-time antivirus protection during install**

I had a very similar issue:

> info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
>
> info: latest update on 2019-07-04, rust version 1.36.0 (a53f9df32 2019-07-03)
>
> info: downloading component 'rustc'
>    91.1 MiB /  91.1 MiB (100 %) 777.6 KiB/s in  1m 30s ETA:  0s
>
> info: downloading component 'rust-std'
>    61.3 MiB /  61.3 MiB (100 %) 269.1 KiB/s in  6m  2s ETA:  0s
>
> info: downloading component 'cargo'
>     4.6 MiB /   4.6 MiB (100 %) 499.2 KiB/s in 10s ETA:  0s
>
> info: downloading component 'rust-docs'
>    11.0 MiB /  11.0 MiB (100 %) 128.8 KiB/s in  1m 24s ETA:  0s
>
> info: installing component 'rustc'
>    91.1 MiB /  91.1 MiB (100 %)   8.7 MiB/s in  9s ETA:  0s
>
> info: installing component 'rust-std'
>    61.3 MiB /  61.3 MiB (100 %)  11.4 MiB/s in  5s ETA:  0s
>
> info: installing component 'cargo'
>
> info: installing component 'rust-docs'
>    11.0 MiB /  11.0 MiB (100 %) 537.6 KiB/s in 44s ETA:  0s
>
> info: rolling back changes
>   error: could not rename component file from '/home/dg/.rustup/tmp/k_625bkits6oph6j_dir/rust-docs/share/doc/rust/html' to '/home/dg/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/share/doc/rust/html'
>
> info: caused by: Permission denied (os error 13)

I read [this thread - Installing rust-docs component on Windows 10 is very slow](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup.rs/issues/1540) about an issue with the unpacking of the documentation on windows. They mention the anti-virus contributes to issues with speed.

I turned off my anti-virus real-time protection and ran the install script again, this time with no issues.

> info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
>
> info: latest update on 2019-07-04, rust version 1.36.0 (a53f9df32 2019-07-03)
>
> info: downloading component 'rustc'
>
> info: downloading component 'rust-std'
>
> info: downloading component 'cargo'
>
> info: downloading component 'rust-docs'
>
> info: installing component 'rustc'
>    91.1 MiB /  91.1 MiB (100 %)   9.1 MiB/s in  8s ETA:  0s
>
> info: installing component 'rust-std'
>    61.3 MiB /  61.3 MiB (100 %)  12.2 MiB/s in  5s ETA:  0s
>
> info: installing component 'cargo'
>
> info: installing component 'rust-docs'
>    11.0 MiB /  11.0 MiB (100 %) 299.2 KiB/s in 27s ETA:  0s
>
> info: default toolchain set to 'stable'
>
> stable installed - rustc 1.36.0 (a53f9df32 2019-07-03)
>
> Rust is installed now. Great!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone on WSL 2 try this:

```
export RUSTUP_IO_THREADS=1
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```